# SQL Server specify mdf file name when restoring database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to restore a database from a BAK file using the following command to perform unit test on a clean copy of the db:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDbUnitTest FROM DISK = 'c:\db\MyDb.bak';
```

it tries to restore the database bu throws an error that MyDb.mdf is in use - and it's correct - it is - by the original database that's used for development on my machine.

Is there a way to specify the name of the MDF file that it will import it along side the development db?

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: You want to use `WITH MOVE`. This is [covered in the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **might be** because you have a tail-log backup being done on the restore.

Change to this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\db\MyDb.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'MyDb' TO N'C:\db\MyDb2.mdf',  MOVE N'Mydb_log' TO N'D:\SQLLogs\MyDb2_log.ldf',  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
RESTORE LOG [MyDB2] FROM  [MyDB_Log] WITH  FILE = 3,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

**Please note the numbers listed pertain to an example of my environment, so you need to ensure you modify this to fit your needs.**

Another way to do this without a script is to simply right click on the database name in management studio and select **Tasks->Restore->Database**.  Then on the options tab remove the "Take tail-log backup before restore" option.

Easiest way to do that is to do it from within management studio and have management studio generate the script for you as shown:

[image]

Comment: JonH how do you know the Log backup is on position 3 in the backup file ??? or the fullback is in position 1 ?? how did you get all this information ?

Comment: @M.Ali - this was an example using my database, he needs to modify this to fit his needs.  Easiest way is to use my second suggestion, and generate a script from that.

Comment: Well then you would give this person the tool to catch the fish, OP needs to do a restore `FILELISTONLY` and `HEADERONLY` to actually get the backup file positions and file names and then use the restore command to restore the database and moving files to appropriate location.

Comment: @M.Ali - please be patient when I post an answer as you see I add specific information pertaining to my environment.  Don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that this is a tail-log problem. From what I can gather this is just a file name conflict from trying to restore a copy of a database on the same server.

Comment: Just from prior experience, try to restore an active database without this.

Comment: ??? The OP is trying to restore a backup as a copy, so new database name, not trying to replace an existing database. They backed up db A and want to restore it as db B. They can't do that because both databases have the same data/log file specifications. So they need to use WITH MOVE.

Comment: Exactly aaron - i do it all the time.  Please try what I posted, note this is sql 2014.  PS: if you generated the script as I've shown above you'd also use WITH MOVE.

Comment: Your first statement is `This is because you have a tail-log backup being done on the restore.` I am not saying your script won't work (since WITH MOVE will resolve the actual issue), I am just saying that your declaration of what is wrong is not necessarily true. I can replicate the problem the OP is having without introducing any issues with logs.

Comment: No problem, this is an editable type system, edit where you see fit.

Comment: I don't like to just edit other people's posts - I think comments and discussion are more valuable. Plus, a lot of people get downright uppity when you start changing their words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know whats in this backup file. Therefore you need to check the content of this file by doing two types of restores before you can actually resotre a database from this backup.

**HEADERONLY RESTORE**

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = N'c:\db\MyDb.bak'
GO
```

This will give the list of backups in this backup file. You should be looking for database `MyDb` with Backup type = 1. Get the position of that file and do 
the following

**FILELISTONLY RESTORE**

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = N'c:\db\MyDb.bak'
 WITH FILE = 1   --<-- this will be the position of the backup from headerOnly restore
GO
```

This will return all the files for that database in that backup.

Primary file , any .ndf and Log file name.

Use these file names and write the restore command like this....

**Database Restore**

```
RESTORE [DatabaseName]
 FROM DISK = N'c:\db\MyDb.bak'
 WITH RECOVERY , 
 MOVE N'PrimaryFile' TO N'C:\Folder\MyDB.mdf',    --<-- should be a valid path
 MOVE N'LogFile'     TO N'C:\Folder\MyDB_Logs.ldf' --<-- should be a valid path
 -- anymore files ......
 GO
```

Comment: @MAli My guess is sour grapes and an assumption that you were also a down-voter. [Don't worry about it and move on](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qaSC5.png).

Comment: @AaronBertrand yep true :)

Comment: It's worth nothing that this answer pushed me in the right direction to discovering the equivalent calls in the SMO library (Restore.ReadFileList and Restore.ReadMediaHeader).

Answer (score -3):

Here's what I use (in a batch file) to restore a specific already-existing database from backup.  The "Replace" causes it to over-write the existing files, so I don't need to specify them.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [%DatabaseName%] 
FROM DISK = N'%DestinationFolder%\%backupFile%' 
WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

This may not serve your needs *exactly*, **but I thought it might be useful for others searching on this issue.**

(Obviously you'd either set environment variables DatatbaseName, DestinationFold, and backupFile ... or replace those place-holders with the hard-coded names and paths and such for your specific purpose... just wanted to be clear about that)

(And if you just script out creating the database you want to restore to first, then restoring to it WITH REPLACE should work as well, leaving you both your original database, and the restored copy of it, both functional, as expected)

For the sake of being even more relevant, here's a script I cobbled together that will restore any backup to any database (whether it exists or not), and does the appropriate MOVE to always work:

```
USE master;

DECLARE @dbNameDestination sysname
DECLARE @backupFileName nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @restoreSql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @mdfFile nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @ldfFile nvarchar(400)

SET @dbNameDestination = 'TestUserTest'   -- The name of the database you want to restore to
SET @backupFileName = 'D:\DB\TestDB.bak'  -- The full path to the *.bak file you wish to restore

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = @dbNameDestination)
BEGIN
    -- Create Destination DB
    SET @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE [' + @dbNameDestination + ']'
    EXEC (@sql)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Force other users off:
    SET @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbNameDestination + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE'
    EXEC (@sql);
    SET @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbNameDestination + '] SET MULTI_USER'
    EXEC (@sql);
END

-- Restore database WITH REPLACE
SET @params = '@mdfOUT nvarchar(400) OUTPUT, @ldfOut nvarchar(400) OUTPUT'
SET @sql = N'USE ' + @dbNameDestination + N';
SELECT @mdfOUT = physical_name FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 0
SELECT @ldfOUT = physical_name FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 1'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @sql, @params, @mdfOUT=@mdfFile OUTPUT, @ldfOUT=@ldfFile OUTPUT

DECLARE @FileList TABLE ( 
    LogicalName nvarchar(128) NOT NULL, 
    PhysicalName nvarchar(260) NOT NULL, 
    Type char(1) NOT NULL, 
    FileGroupName nvarchar(120) NULL, 
    Size numeric(20, 0) NOT NULL, 
    MaxSize numeric(20, 0) NOT NULL, 
    FileID bigint NULL, 
    CreateLSN numeric(25,0) NULL, 
    DropLSN numeric(25,0) NULL, 
    UniqueID uniqueidentifier NULL, 
    ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0) NULL , 
    ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0) NULL, 
    BackupSizeInBytes bigint NULL, 
    SourceBlockSize int NULL, 
    FileGroupID int NULL, 
    LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier NULL, 
    DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0)NULL, 
    DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier NULL, 
    IsReadOnly bit NULL, 
    IsPresent bit NULL, 
    TDEThumbprint varbinary(32) NULL 
 ); 

SET @restoreSql =  N'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK=N''' + @backupFileName + '''' 
INSERT INTO @FileList EXEC(@restoreSql); 

DECLARE @logical_data nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @logical_log nvarchar(max); 
SET @logical_data = (SELECT [LogicalName] FROM @FileList WHERE [Type] = 'D' AND [FileID] = 1) 
SET @logical_log = (SELECT [LogicalName] FROM @FileList WHERE [Type] = 'L' AND [FileID] = 2) 

-- Now issue RESTORE command
RESTORE DATABASE @dbNameDestination 
FROM DISK = @backupFileName 
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE @logical_data TO @mdfFile, 
MOVE @logical_log TO @ldfFile 
GO
```

Just edit the two constants at the top of the script, to specify the database name to restore to (whether or not it already exists), and the full path to the backup file you wish to restore.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71792/discussion-on-answer-by-pmbaustin-sql-server-specify-mdf-file-name-when-restorin).